# Javascript change style on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

i have a little jquery script :

```
 $('.product_types > li').click(function() {
 $(this)
    .css('backgroundColor','#EE178C')
    .siblings()
    .css('backgroundColor','#ffffff');
   // $('.product_types > li').removeClass(backgroundColor);

});
```

that colors me a div onclick. The problem is that i want only the last element clicked to be colored. And i dont know can i remove the style (the css style) after every click ?

thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem... the last element clicked _is_ coloured, and the others aren't. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/RysVx/).

Comment: @Town: Click on element #1 and its color changes. Then click on element #2. When we click on #2, we want to not only change it to the new color, but also change #1 back to its original color.

Comment: @DOK: Is that assuming that the original colour is _not_ white?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a css class like `.lastClicked` and using jquery to remove all instances of `.lastClicked` when a new element is clicked.

```
.lastClicked{ background-color:#EE178C; }
.lastClicked (siblingName) { background-color: #ffffff; }
```

your jquery code would look something like:

```
$('.product_types > li').click(function() { 
  $(".lastClicked").removeClass("lastClicked");
  $(this).addClass("lastClicked");});
```

Comment: Nice solution :D However, you need to trigger a lookup on the DOM to retrieve $(".lastClicked"), which is useless if you store taht in a variable.

Comment: @deadalnix - yeah, absolutely right, but you beat me to posting my idea, so I figured I'd make a quick modification and post another option~

Answer (score 2):

You can store lastly clicked element in global variable, and on click reset its color :

```
var lastElm = null
$('.product_types > li').click(function() {
  if( lastElm ) $(lastElm).css('backgroundColor','#[Your original color]')
  lastElm = this;
 $(this)
    .css('backgroundColor','#EE178C')
    .siblings()
    .css('backgroundColor','#ffffff');
   // $('.product_types > li').removeClass(backgroundColor);

});
```

Comment: I don't know jquery, but this is the method I use in plain old JavaScript :)

Comment: i don't know jQuery too, but this is to simple to find out

Comment: You're setting the `background-color` of `lastElm` to `[Your original color]` but then (assuming that `lastElm` is a sibling of the current element) setting its `background-color` to white anyway, so this will do the same as the code in the question, only less efficiently.

Comment: lastElm is setted to current element right after this color change ( line 4 )

Comment: Even if it answer the question, this sample code is full of bad practices, which will leads to problems in the future devellopement of the script. First, lastEleme is global, so it can be modified by some other script. This si not relyable. You mix display properties and code logic, and assume useless preconditions to be filled (all dovs have the same background color and xhtml structure ensure that '.product_types > li' are sibling). I would definitively not use that sample code in one of my programs.

Answer (score 2):

You need a variable that store the actual colored div and remove style on it. Something like this (not tested) should do the trick :

```
(function(){
var coloredDiv = null;

$('.product_types > li').click(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    if(coloredDiv != null) coloredDiv.removeClass('someCSSClassThatColorMyDiv');
    item.addClass('someCSSClassThatColorMyDiv');
    coloredDiv = item;
});

})();
```

NB: I also suggest to use CSS class instead of manualy set the CSS property in the Javascript. This leads to better separating of the code logic and displaying.

I also put the whole stuff in a closure so the variable cannot be overriden by some other script by mistake.